How to know which repository to add to dnf to install a particular application in RHEL?
I'm a long time Windows user trying to transition to using Linux as my main O/S.

I am using RHEL 9.3 (Plow) 64-bit.
I am trying to install Shutter.
When I run dnf install shutter as directed here I get the following error message:

sudo dnf install shutter [sudo] password for simon: Updating
Subscription Management repositories. Last metadata expiration check:
0:08:13 ago on Sat 06 Apr 2024 13:38:27 BST. No match for argument:
shutter Error: Unable to find a match: shutter

I've done some Googling/ChatGPT and I'm lead to believe this is because dnf, the package manager, cannot find a package with the name 'shutter' in the repositories it has currently enabled.
My question: How do I reliably know which repositories I need to add to dnf to install a particular application? Is there some sort of search engine? I'm semi-surprised the Shutter project haven't listed this on their website, but I'm not seeing it on the website of other projects either which leaves me thinking there must be something fundamentally wrong with my approach.
Note: I have tried adding the EPEL repository but this does not list shutter:
✘ simon@localhost  /  dnf repolist
Not root, Subscription Management repositories not updated
repo id                                                                                                                                          repo name
code                                                                                                                                             Visual Studio Code
codeready-builder-for-rhel-9-x86_64-rpms                                                                                                         Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for RHEL 9 x86_64 (RPMs)
epel                                                                                                                                             Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 - x86_64
epel-cisco-openh264                                                                                                                              Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 9 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64
google-chrome                                                                                                                                    google-chrome
rhel-9-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms                                                                                                                 Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)
rhel-9-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms                                                                                                                    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 9 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)
 simon@localhost  /  dnf list --available | grep -i shutter
 ✘ simon@localhost  /  


"I've done some Googling/ChatGPT and I'm lead to believe this is because dnf, the package manager, cannot find a package with the name 'shutter' in the repositories it has currently enabled." No need for ChatGPT, that's literally what the output of dnf says. Generally, don't ask ChatGPT when you need facts. It is literally a "make plausible-sounding stuff up" machine, not a "give me an answer machine", no matter the marketing. The optimization goal when training such an LLM is not to give correct answers, but to give answers that can't be distinguished from things that sound good.


How do I reliably know which repositories I need to add to dnf to install a particular application?

On RHEL, chances are you want EPEL, a community effort to bring the packages that other distros (mostly, Fedora) have, but that Red Hat doesn't provide support for, to RHEL. dnf install -y epel-release; dnf check-update to enable it.
However, in this case, shutter is also not in EPEL.

Is there some sort of search engine?

There re a couple, but I'd recommend doing what you did: first investigate the homepage of the project. If that doesn't yield anything, and neither Red Hat's official sources nor EPEL have shutter, that means you need to rely on third-party packaging; and that's not a great situation, because you need to first find someone who, out of an abundance of time, probably, has packaged your software of interest for your specific distro, but then did not take steps to "upstream" that package, which means they didn't work with the project to make that something officially recommended by the software developers, nor with the distro/EPEL, to make that officially endorsed by a packager community. This is usually the case for "experimental" packaging / software, or when just nobody has yet cared to do that.
I think, while shutter still is in the "we're still experimental" versioning numbers (you usually don't release things as version 0.something unless you want to tell people that it still isn't ready for end-users), the latter is the case: nobody sat down and took the Fedora package and tried to make a RHEL package out of it (which is usually quite straightforward), submitted it to EPEL and dedicated time to take care of it whenever updates roll in.
So, I'd guess you won't find anything on the usual search engines:

https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/package-browser for packages in RHEL
https://repology.org for things in official software repositories
https://www.rpmfind.org for RPM-using distros (Fedora, RHEL, CentOS, Alma, Rocky, Amazon, Oracle, SUSE Linux…)
https://packages.debian.org for Debian, and replace Debian with Ubuntu for Ubuntu packages

Bad luck! You'll need to build the software yourself, or use an alternative screenshot program, like the one that came with your desktop environment already.
Building the software yourself isn't going to be very hard, usually. Shutter, however doesn't come with a list of dependencies, it misses a build system to detect dependencies on your system, so you'd really need to do what typically is the job of the upstream developers to make things work on RHEL. Honestly, maybe shutter is still a bit too experimental for that. Stick with something a slight bit better-supported until someone figured out how to package things correctly.
Just for someone to actually try this out, the steps on RHEL 9 would be something like this to port that package over from Fedora. This is untested, and I'll not help debug it. This doesn't even try to correct for naming differences in packages between Fedora and RHEL, and you can expect that you'll need to port dependencies of shutter, as well. Writing a screenshot utility for modern desktops in Perl in 2024 is honestly not a very easy to port choice; Perl is a great language for a lot of purposes, but it's definitely not been the most popular for graphical applications in the last 20 years.
RPMNAME=shutter
sudo dnf install -y epel-release
sudo dnf install -y --refresh fedpkg
fedpkg clone --anonymous "rpms/${RPMNAME}"
cd "${RPMNAME}"
fedpkg mockbuild
# after the build there will be a results* subdirectory
# bash: enable recursive globs
shopt -s globstar
sudo dnf install result*/**/*.rpm


Given that the package is in Fedora, it’s also possible to ask for it to be added to EPEL — if the dependencies are available, it’s not much effort. Knowing that users want a package is half the battle.

@StephenKitt you got me, so I copy and pasted my script into an almalinux 9 + EPEL container, and basically none of the Perl dependencies exist. I don't think you can just ask "generically", you'll need someone willing to take up maintainership, explictly.

Ah of course I'm wrong, EPEL's just an extra branch, indeed.

I’ve been on the receiving end of requests for an EPEL branch, that’s how I know ;-).

thing is, I should have known, because I've been asked the same (signifiy, to be specific)
